# How to call an async method after async controller action method being executed in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

What I am trying to do is to execute `await unitOfWork.CommitChanges()` after each action method of each controller (and, possibly, return an invalid result to indicate that error occurred) for "Transaction Per Request" feature.

For now, I've tried to use custom AsyncActionInvoker for this purpose overriding `EndInvokeActionMethod` and using `.Wait()` method inside it. I think it can cause issues and generally not a good approach. Also, I am using a synchronous variant of `.CommitChanges()` inside overridden `InvokeAction` in order to make it work in the same manner for synchronous action methods. Here is the full example:

```
public class UnitOfWorkActionInvocker : AsyncControllerActionInvoker, IAsyncActionInvoker, IActionInvoker
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public UnitOfWorkActionInvocker(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public override bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
    {
        this.unitOfWork.CommitChanges();
        return base.InvokeAction(controllerContext, actionName);
    }

    public override bool EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        this.unitOfWork.CommitChangesAsync().Wait();
        return base.EndInvokeAction(asyncResult);
    }
}
```

I've thought about using async ActionFilter for that purpose but it is presented only in WebApi. Mvc has only sync ActionFilters.

Is it possible to call an async method inside EndInvokeAction **asynchronously**? Are there better options?

Comment: Asynchronous action filters are a known limitation of ASP.NET MVC 5. ASP.NET Core has support for them.

Comment: Yeah, but may be there are any ways to play around IAsyncResult in AsyncActionInvoker?

Comment: Possibly; I haven't tried that approach, but it looks like it would work. Not as nice-to-use as filters, for sure.